# How to read multiple com ports from a single port in java?

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to read multiple serial ports (in which multiple devices are connected) from a single USB serial port.

How is it possible? Anybody tell me how to fix this problem. Please refer some tutorials or websites.

Comment: AFAIK if you attach multiple devices to the same serial port, they will appear as multiple serial devices. You don't need to know they were plugged in via a hub.

Comment: ok. thanks for your reply. how to find a particular device id(ex., energy meter) from multiple devices?

Comment: for energy meter, slave id = 1. how to find this automatically using code?